# Resistance Calculator

Tags: c

So I'm trying to build a program to calculate resistance for either parallel or series circuits. The formula for calculating parallel resistance is:

```
1/R_t = (1/R_1) + (1/R_2) + (1/R_n)...
```

The problem I'm having is that the program outputs "-1.#QNAN0" for parallel resistance calculations. Any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int n, choice, i;
char sel;
float res_tot, inv_res_tot;

printf("This is a program that calculates resistance.\n");

do{
    printf("Enter 1 for parallel or 2 for series: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    printf("How many resistors are there: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\n");

    double r[n];

    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Resistor %d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%lf", &r[i]);
    }

    if(choice==1) {
        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            inv_res_tot+=(1/r[i]);
        }

        res_tot=(1/inv_res_tot);
    }   

    else if(choice==2) {
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
            res_tot+=r[i];
        }   
    }

    printf("\nThe total resistance is: %f Ohms\n", res_tot);

    printf("\nWould you like to calculate another(y/n): ");
    getchar();
    scanf("%c", &sel);

} while(sel=='Y' || sel=='y');



return(0);  
}
```

Comment: What specifically is your input and expected output?

Comment: You really don't need to store the values into array, you can calculate it on the fly.

Comment: Try initializing `inv_res_tot`.  And `n`.  Weird uninitialized values could definitely explain your weird result.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize `inv_res_tot` and `res_tot`.

You should do this in each iteration of the `while loop`.

http://ideone.com/Dgv4kJ